# Android EditText Widget Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

How Can i reduce the size of the EditText widget? I've tried the android:layout_height property, it reduces the size but it cuts down the text too. I need to fit the widget into my design layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:maxLines=1 (2,3..) in your xml declaration

Comment: how will that decrease the height? i don't think so!

Comment: if you put a maxLines=1 the EditText can't be 200 px, it can be as tall as a 1 line EditText can get